# easy way to reverse series data points on an asp .net c# 4.0 chart control

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

As always I am going to get chastised for not providing enough code but I think I can describe this with minimal code and am hoping for a one line answer if it exists.  If not I know how to code it myself with a small amount of effort.

I have a chart with a single series and chart area.  In my code I add points dynamically like so:

```
Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(1,1)
Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(2,2)
Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(3,3)
```

I am wondering if theres any way with a single function call or something easy and painless to rotate the points around the Y axis aka the furthest point on the right would appear on the left and vice versa

To put it another way it would be a function call that would basically act as if i had added the points in the opposite order aka:

```
Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(3,3)
Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(2,2)
Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(1,1)
```

thanks!

Comment: Are you setting a datasource? Could you post this datasource?

Comment: i am adding the points individually as shown in the code above

Comment: I added an answer. I hope that is what you are looking for, if not, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Go through a for or foreach loop and push each point onto a stack. Then pop them back off the stack and add them back. You could also use a `List.Reverse()` method if your items are in a list.